# SUM Duration by reason

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On our fleet management system at the mine, we have a way to keep track of how much time a Excavator spent in a specific state. I now need to calculate how much time was spent per state. My query and tables are below. I need to join 3 different tables to get dates, reasons, duration and reason codes in order to make this work. I just can't seem to get the time of individual reasons to sum, it keeps on splitting the time.

```
select

       hs.shiftindex
      ,hs.reason
      ,hs.status
      ,sum(duration/60) as minutes
      ,rtrim(hr.name) as reason 

from hist_statusevents as hs 
inner join hist_reasontable as hr on 
hr.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex and 
hr.reason = hs.reason
inner join hist_exproot as he on 
he.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex 

where shiftdate = '2017-12-13'
and eqmt in ('ex02','ex03','ex04','ex05','ex06','ex07') 
and hs.status <>2
and hs.status <>1
and hr.name not like ('SHIFT CHANGE')
and hs.reason in ('7005','5010','6615','6705')
group by hs.shiftindex, duration, hs.reason, hs.status, hr.name
order by duration desc
```

Tables:
hist_statusevents:

```
shiftindex  cliID   ddbkey  eqmt    unit    operid  starttime   endtime duration    reason  status  category    comment vEvent  reasonlink  stdcomm
52139   31172   2374056 EX02    2   mmsunk  0   1406    1406    6011    4   3       0   2303324 Other
52139   31172   2374246 EX02    2   001314  1406    1872    466 6011    4   3       0   2303324 Other
52139   31172   2374436 EX02    2   001314  1872    4402    2530    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2374626 EX02    2   001314  4402    4650    248 6028    4   3       1   2373950 Other
52139   31172   2374816 EX02    2   001314  4650    5583    933 7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2375006 EX02    2   001314  5583    6059    476 6031    4   3       1   2372134 Other
52139   31172   2375196 EX02    2   001314  6059    17100   11041   7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2375386 EX02    2   001314  17100   17791   691 5124    3   4       1   2306302 Other
52139   31172   2375576 EX02    2   001314  17791   21701   3910    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2375766 EX02    2   001314  21701   22056   355 6028    4   3       1   2373950 Other
52139   31172   2375956 EX02    2   001314  22056   22987   931 7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2376146 EX02    2   001314  22987   24119   1132    5010    4   2       1   417238  Other
52139   31172   2376336 EX02    2   001314  24119   28800   4681    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2376526 EX03    2   mmsunk  0   734 734 7000    2   1       0   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2376716 EX03    2   mmsunk  734 735 1   5060    4   3       1   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2376906 EX03    2   mmsunk  735 1442    707 5060    4   3       0   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2377096 EX03    2   001311  1442    1460    18  5060    4   3       0   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2377286 EX03    2   001311  1460    1468    8   5060    4   3       0   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2377476 EX03    2   001311  1468    2663    1195    6033    3   4       1   2356152 Other
52139   31172   2377666 EX03    2   001311  2663    6943    4280    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2377856 EX03    2   001311  6943    7340    397 6000    4   3       1   2306408 Other
52139   31172   2378046 EX03    2   001311  7340    22911   15571   7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2378236 EX03    2   001311  22911   24095   1184    5010    4   2       1   417238  Other
52139   31172   2378426 EX03    2   001311  24095   28800   4705    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2378616 EX04    2   mmsunk  0   28800   28800   3000    1   6   1000 HRS SERVICE    0   2302604 1000 HRS SERVICE
52139   31172   2378806 EX05    2   mmsunk  0   28800   28800   1705    1   5   RING GEAR FAILURE   0   408122  Other
52139   31172   2379102 EX06    2   mmsunk  0   970 970 7000    2   1       0   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2379292 EX06    2   mmsunk  970 1323    353 5010    4   2       1   417238  Other
52139   31172   2379482 EX06    2   mmsunk  1323    1337    14  7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2379672 EX06    2   003455  1337    6844    5507    7000    2   1       0   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2379862 EX06    2   003455  6844    7584    740 6034    3   4       1   2378996 Other
52139   31172   2380052 EX06    2   003455  7584    20820   13236   7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2380242 EX06    2   003455  20820   21605   785 6040    4   3       1   2308900 Other
52139   31172   2380432 EX06    2   003455  21605   22908   1303    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2380622 EX06    2   003455  22908   24493   1585    5010    4   2       1   417238  Other
52139   31172   2380812 EX06    2   003455  24493   28800   4307    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2381108 EX07    2   mmsunk  0   240 240 7000    2   1       0   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2381298 EX07    2   mmsunk  240 386 146 6033    3   4       1   2356152 Other
52139   31172   2381488 EX07    2   mmsunk  386 1380    994 6033    3   4       0   2356152 Other
52139   31172   2381678 EX07    2   mmsunk  1380    1623    243 5060    4   3       1   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2381868 EX07    2   001479  1623    2098    475 5060    4   3       0   2303112 Other
52139   31172   2382058 EX07    2   001479  2098    3780    1682    7000    2   1       1   2303006 Other
52139   31172   2382248 EX07    2   001479  3780    4379    599 6000    4   3       1   2306408 Other
52164   31172   1987914 EX02    2   mmsunk  0   1038    1038    100 2   1       0   405860  Other
52164   31172   1988104 EX02    2   mmsunk  1038    1487    449 6315    3   4       1   408616  Other
52164   31172   1988294 EX02    2   001196  1487    1906    419 6315    3   4       0   408616  Other
52164   31172   1988484 EX02    2   001196  1906    16191   14285   100 2   1       1   405860  Other
52164   31172   1988674 EX02    2   001196  16191   20599   4408    5105    4   3       1   411372  Other
52164   31172   1988864 EX02    2   001196  20599   20823   224 100 2   1       1   405860  Other
52164   31172   1989054 EX02    2   001196  20823   22041   1218    6905    4   3       1   415082  Other
```

hist_reasontable:

```
shiftindex  cliID   ddbkey  name    reason  status  delaytime   category    mainttime   altname center
52139   31172   396992  Control 510 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397098  Motor   515 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397204  Saddle Blocks   520 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397310  Tension System  525 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397416  Transmission    530 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397522  MECHANICAL DRIVE    600 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397628  Controls    610 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397734  Differential    615 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397840  Dynamics Retarder   620 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   397946  Final Drive 625 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398052  Tandem Drive    630 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398158  Torque Converter    635 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398264  ELECTRICAL-PROPULSION   640 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398370  TRANSMISSION    645 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398476  Wheel Motor 650 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398582  ELECTRICAL  700 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398688  Control 705 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398794  Lighting    710 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   398900  Motor   715 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399006  Transformer 720 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399112  Electrical 12/24 Volts  800 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399218  Alt 805 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399324  Battery 810 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399430  Control 815 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399536  ELECTRICAL-LIGHTING 820 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399642  Starter 825 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399748  Wiring  830 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399854  ELECTRICAL-POWER FAILURE    900 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   399960  Reel / Stinger  905 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400066  Switch Gear 910 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400172  Transformer 915 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400278  Aux Transformer 920 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400384  Centurion System    925 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400490  Collector   930 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400596  Converter/Inverter  935 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400702  Load Centers    940 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400808  MCC 945 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   400914  ELECTRICAL-ZESCO EXTERNAL   950 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401020  Reactive Power  955 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401126  Transformer 960 1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401232  ENGINE  1000    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401338  Controls    1005    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401444  ENGINE-COOLING SYSTEM   1010    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401550  Complete Engine 1015    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401656  Exhaust 1020    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401762  OTHER-FUEL TANK 1025    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401868  Intake  1030    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   401974  Lubes   1035    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   402080  Hoist   1100    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
52139   31172   402186  Brake   1105    1   1200    6   NO      01. Availability
```

hist_exproot:

```
shiftdate   cliID   ddbkey  shiftindex  name    year    month#  month   day shift#  shift   date    start   crew#   crew    len disptime    holiday ddmmyy  finyear finquarter  finmonth    finweek
2017-09-15 00:00:00 31172   0   52274   15-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 15  3   Night Shift 1505512800  79200   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   15-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-19 00:00:00 31172   0   52285   19-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 19  2   Aft Shift   1505829600  50400   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   19-09-17    2017    3   9   38
2017-10-21 00:00:00 31172   0   52382   21-OCT-17 Night Shift   17  10  OCT 21  3   Night Shift 1508623200  79200   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   21-10-17    2017    4   10  43
2017-09-11 00:00:00 31172   0   52261   11-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 11  2   Aft Shift   1505138400  50400   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   11-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-01 00:00:00 31172   0   52232   01-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 1   3   Night Shift 1504303200  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   01-09-17    2017    3   9   35
2017-09-13 00:00:00 31172   0   52266   13-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 13  1   Day Shift   1505282400  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   13-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-10-24 00:00:00 31172   0   52391   24-OCT-17 Night Shift   17  10  OCT 24  3   Night Shift 1508882400  79200   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   24-10-17    2017    4   10  43
2017-08-31 00:00:00 31172   0   52227   31-AUG-17 Day Shift 17  8   AUG 31  1   Day Shift   1504159200  21600   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   31-08-17    2017    3   8   35
2017-10-23 00:00:00 31172   0   52386   23-OCT-17 Day Shift 17  10  OCT 23  1   Day Shift   1508738400  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   23-10-17    2017    4   10  43
2017-08-29 00:00:00 31172   0   52221   29-AUG-17 Day Shift 17  8   AUG 29  1   Day Shift   1503986400  21600   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   29-08-17    2017    3   8   35
2017-08-30 00:00:00 31172   0   52226   30-AUG-17 Night Shift   17  8   AUG 30  3   Night Shift 1504130400  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   30-08-17    2017    3   8   35
2017-09-16 00:00:00 31172   0   52276   16-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 16  2   Aft Shift   1505570400  50400   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   16-09-17    2017    3   9   38
2017-09-15 00:00:00 31172   0   52272   15-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 15  1   Day Shift   1505455200  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   15-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-05 00:00:00 31172   0   52244   05-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 5   3   Night Shift 1504648800  79200   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   05-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-07 00:00:00 31172   0   52248   07-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 7   1   Day Shift   1504764000  21600   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   07-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-04 00:00:00 31172   0   52240   04-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 4   2   Aft Shift   1504533600  50400   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   04-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-02 00:00:00 31172   0   52234   02-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 2   2   Aft Shift   1504360800  50400   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   02-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-02 00:00:00 31172   0   52233   02-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 2   1   Day Shift   1504332000  21600   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   02-09-17    2017    3   9   35
2017-09-07 00:00:00 31172   0   52250   07-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 7   3   Night Shift 1504821600  79200   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   07-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-07 00:00:00 31172   0   52249   07-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 7   2   Aft Shift   1504792800  50400   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   07-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-06 00:00:00 31172   0   52246   06-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 6   2   Aft Shift   1504706400  50400   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   06-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-11-21 00:00:00 31172   0   52473   21-NOV-17 Day Shift 17  11  NOV 21  1   Day Shift   1511244000  21600   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   21-11-17    2017    4   11  47
2017-08-29 00:00:00 31172   0   52223   29-AUG-17 Night Shift   17  8   AUG 29  3   Night Shift 1504044000  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   29-08-17    2017    3   8   35
2017-08-31 00:00:00 31172   0   52229   31-AUG-17 Night Shift   17  8   AUG 31  3   Night Shift 1504216800  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   31-08-17    2017    3   8   35
2017-09-06 00:00:00 31172   0   52247   06-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 6   3   Night Shift 1504735200  79200   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   06-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-02 00:00:00 31172   0   52235   02-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 2   3   Night Shift 1504389600  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   02-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-10-18 00:00:00 31172   0   52372   18-OCT-17 Aft Shift 17  10  OCT 18  2   Aft Shift   1508335200  50400   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   18-10-17    2017    4   10  42
2017-09-04 00:00:00 31172   0   52239   04-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 4   1   Day Shift   1504504800  21600   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   04-09-17    2017    3   9   36
2017-09-16 00:00:00 31172   0   52275   16-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 16  1   Day Shift   1505541600  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   16-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-16 00:00:00 31172   0   52277   16-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 16  3   Night Shift 1505599200  79200   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   16-09-17    2017    3   9   38
2017-10-31 00:00:00 31172   0   52411   31-OCT-17 Aft Shift 17  10  OCT 31  2   Aft Shift   1509458400  50400   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   31-10-17    2017    4   10  44
2017-10-25 00:00:00 31172   0   52393   25-OCT-17 Aft Shift 17  10  OCT 25  2   Aft Shift   1508940000  50400   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   25-10-17    2017    4   10  43
2017-10-20 00:00:00 31172   0   52377   20-OCT-17 Day Shift 17  10  OCT 20  1   Day Shift   1508479200  21600   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   20-10-17    2017    4   10  42
2017-09-11 00:00:00 31172   0   52262   11-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 11  3   Night Shift 1505167200  79200   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   11-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-14 00:00:00 31172   0   52270   14-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 14  2   Aft Shift   1505397600  50400   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   14-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-08-02 00:00:00 31172   0   52141   02-AUG-17 Aft Shift 17  8   AUG 2   2   Aft Shift   1501682400  50400   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   02-08-17    2017    3   8   31
2017-08-01 00:00:00 31172   0   52137   01-AUG-17 Day Shift 17  8   AUG 1   1   Day Shift   1501567200  21600   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   01-08-17    2017    3   8   31
2017-09-17 00:00:00 31172   0   52278   17-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 17  1   Day Shift   1505628000  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   17-09-17    2017    3   9   38
2017-07-31 00:00:00 31172   0   52135   31-JUL-17 Aft Shift 17  7   JUL 31  2   Aft Shift   1501509600  50400   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   31-07-17    2017    3   7   31
2017-09-10 00:00:00 31172   0   52258   10-SEP-17 Aft Shift 17  9   SEP 10  2   Aft Shift   1505052000  50400   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   10-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-20 00:00:00 31172   0   52289   20-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 20  3   Night Shift 1505944800  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   20-09-17    2017    3   9   38
2017-12-03 00:00:00 31172   0   52510   03-DEC-17 Aft Shift 17  12  DEC 3   2   Aft Shift   1512309600  50400   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   03-12-17    2017    4   12  49
2017-09-10 00:00:00 31172   0   52259   10-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 10  3   Night Shift 1505080800  79200   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   10-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-13 00:00:00 31172   0   52268   13-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 13  3   Night Shift 1505340000  79200   3   Crew C  28800   28800   0   13-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-09-14 00:00:00 31172   0   52269   14-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 14  1   Day Shift   1505368800  21600   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   14-09-17    2017    3   9   37
2017-10-21 00:00:00 31172   0   52380   21-OCT-17 Day Shift 17  10  OCT 21  1   Day Shift   1508565600  21600   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   21-10-17    2017    4   10  42
2017-10-11 00:00:00 31172   0   52352   11-OCT-17 Night Shift   17  10  OCT 11  3   Night Shift 1507759200  79200   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   11-10-17    2017    4   10  41
2017-09-30 00:00:00 31172   0   52319   30-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 30  3   Night Shift 1506808800  79200   4   Crew D  28800   28800   0   30-09-17    2017    3   9   40
2017-09-27 00:00:00 31172   0   52310   27-SEP-17 Night Shift   17  9   SEP 27  3   Night Shift 1506549600  79200   1   Crew A  28800   28800   0   27-09-17    2017    3   9   39
2017-09-29 00:00:00 31172   0   52314   29-SEP-17 Day Shift 17  9   SEP 29  1   Day Shift   1506664800  21600   2   Crew B  28800   28800   0   29-09-17    2017    3   9   39
```

What I am getting:

```
reason  reason  status  minutes
Lightning   7005    3   93.31666667
Lightning   7005    3   92.06666667
Lightning   7005    3   70.31666667
Lightning   7005    3   61.3
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   15.4
Waiting on Clean Up 6615    3   14.65
Lightning   7005    3   11.7
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   9.316666667
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   9.116666667
Lightning   7005    3   9.05
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   9
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   7.666666667
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   6.8
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   5.933333333
Restricted Access   6705    4   4.266666667
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   4.15
Waiting on Clean Up 6615    3   3.333333333
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   3
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   2.983333333
```

What I am expecting:

```
reason  reason  status  minutes
Lightning   7005    3   337.75
Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   73.36666667
Waiting on Clean Up 6615    3   17.98333333
Restricted Access   6705    4   4.266666667
```

So what I basically want is a summery, what I am getting at the moment is detailed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: GROUP BY the columns you select that are not arguments to set functions.

Comment: Also realise you have two columns called `reason`, this may be an issue for the software which consumes the data.

Comment: Also, your output doesn't fit your query. Your query has 5 columns, your output 4, and the order of the columns is different too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take duration out of the group by clause and order by minutes:

```
...
group by hs.shiftindex, hs.reason, hs.status, hr.name
order by minutes desc
```

The result columns should all be **either** group by columns **or** aggregates.  If you group by the aggregated column (duration) as well then you get a separate  row for each of the durations.

Comment: Jep, that did the trick, and so simple. Feel so dumb for not spotting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use Over with Sum in your select statement

```
sum(duration/60)over(PARTITION BY hs.reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your group by to include column that you want to be in summary.
Changed your query a bit by adding some aggregate functions.

From the sample data above for those **status** and **reasonname(hr.name)** column you have same data for each reason that you want in the summary so did a `max()` to avoid them using in the group by so as to get the summary you needed. If in case they are different you need have some logic using window functions to select what you need

```
SELECT 
    hs.reason
    ,max(hs.STATUS)
    ,sum(duration / 60) AS minutes
    ,max(rtrim(hr.NAME)) AS reasonname
FROM hist_statusevents AS hs
INNER JOIN hist_reasontable AS hr ON hr.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex
    AND hr.reason = hs.reason
INNER JOIN hist_exproot AS he ON he.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex
WHERE shiftdate = '2017-12-13'
    AND eqmt IN (
        'ex02'
        ,'ex03'
        ,'ex04'
        ,'ex05'
        ,'ex06'
        ,'ex07'
        )
    AND hs.STATUS <> 2
    AND hs.STATUS <> 1
    AND hr.NAME NOT LIKE ('SHIFT CHANGE')
    AND hs.reason IN (
        '7005'
        ,'5010'
        ,'6615'
        ,'6705'
        )
GROUP BY 
    hs.reason
ORDER BY duration DESC
```